# how to define length and width of outputtext in jsf?

Tags: jsf

how to define length and width of outputtext in jsf ?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean exactly by defining "length and width" of outputText?

A `<h:outputText>` will just display a text. So the length of this component will depend on the length of the text to be displayed.

However, you can specify a width for your text, by setting a specific `width` CSS property:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myText}" style="width: 100px;"/>
```

This will create a `<span>` HTML tag that will contains your text. However, if the text is longer than the width defined, the browser will display your text on several lines.

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work. The text still overflows and changes the size of the panel.

Comment: It worked for me perfectly. Without any whitespaces, the text still overflows.

Answer (score 2):

Please add the below style sheet to work properly.

```
style="width: 100px;white-space: normal"
```

It will work what you are expecting.